# Using 2x CAT6 cables for 3D Printer Hot End

Tags: cables

Question was [previously posted on 3D Printing Stack Exchange](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13550/using-2x-cat6-cable-for-24-v-hotend) who recommended that I repost my issues here.

I'm looking to replace the troublesome ribbon cable of my Duplicator 6 with a 2x CAT6 arrangement for all things extruder.

1. I wasn't paying attention when I bought my cable and got 26 AWG cable instead of 24 AWG, I think signs are pointing to me needing to get better cables (CAT6a?) if this idea works at all.
2. How many CAT6 wires do I need to dedicate to the hot end 50 W at 24 V?
3. Can I consolidate ground connections of the low power fans/sensors to free up more wires?
4. Is it okay if I have some pins carry 24 volts (like for the heater) and others carry 12 volts (for the fans)?

EDIT: Updated table to show proposed changes to pinouts. I've obtained 24AWG CAT6 stranded cables to maximize my ampacity.

[image: updated table showing wiring pin outs]

Comment: A few... Someone can easily do the math, but this is not a great way to move hot end power. Run the 2 separate wires for it otherwise... You need to also check the connectors are rated for the current.

Comment: I'd look for CAT5E instead, CAT6 has a stiffening spine up the middle which could be inconvenient

Comment: How long is the cable? Resistance might be a problem but at higher voltages not so much

Comment: Cable to be no longer than 5ft

Comment: What is troublesome about the ribbon cable? Given the actual problem, we might be able to come up with a really good solution;)

Comment: @AndrewMorton the 3d printer in question has a steel case that the ribbon cable would slip through a cut hole, but over time the ribbon rubs against the sharp edge of the hole and gets damaged.

Comment: @GaryZ I thought the usual fix for that was to use the 3D printer to print a grommet to smooth over the rough edge? You can get a set of "ruby abrasive stones" from China which come in a set of various profile (round, half-round, square, triangular) for less than $20 which are great for smoothing sharp edges off things even including glass.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the hole isn't large enough to accommodate such a solution. Also, I'm looking to include the z probe wires in my solution, since they weren't a part of the stock configuration with the ribbon cable.

Comment: @GaryZ "the hole isn't large enough" Aha! A *geniune reason* to buy a Proxxon or Dremel tool! I wish I could afford a larger flat to fit more tools in.

Answer (score 2):

At first thought I blew off CAT6 as a viable option, but thinking about it #26 Wire is not a bad choice.

So to answer your questions:

You should have the same number of power and ground lines in parallel for power delivery like this. \$ 50W/24V= 2.1A\$ Using one of many online calculators for voltage drop, assuming 1ft cable of #26, your looking at 0.7% voltage loss (~1/3W per foot, starting to get warm). 2 cables in parallel that is 0.35%, not to noticeable. ([example here](https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?material=copper&wiresize=133.9&voltage=24&phase=dc&noofconductor=1&distance=1&distanceunit=feet&amperes=2.1&x=92&y=20)) I would suggest using 2 twisted pairs, with power and ground on each pair to reduce inductance and loop area.

**Q1&2:** #26AWG cable is fine if you use 2.

**Q3:** Depends on the amount of power, and how your control board works, if anything uses low side (NFET) switches to control fan speed etc, then common grounds breaks that scheme. Any fan etc. that has speed control I would send independent wires, unless you are sure of how it works.

**Q4:** Yes, mixed voltages are fine.

Final note, you should try to keep things paired with Ethernet/RJ45 pairs.
i.e. run a fan on a twisted pair, don't pick random wires and mix, lookup what pins go to what pair.

Comment: Read Neil's answer also... He has a great point if you use solid core cat6

Comment: I've updated the table to reflect your input, could you look over it and let me know if you think it's reasonable?

Comment: Looks good. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

CAT6 is generally solid cored wire. If the hot end is moving around, then I forecast a relatively short flex life for the connection. You need multi-strand very fine wire for long life.